# How do I change ONLY java modifier text color in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, syntax, colors

I'm having a problem with the syntax coloring for Java in eclipse. I'm trying to change the text color of JUST the java modifiers in eclipse (like public, protected, private), but eclipse's preferences have me change all keywords that are not 'return' into one color. i'm trying to do this because my modifier and return type are right next to each other and i'd like them to be different colors. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried wwww.eclipsecolorthemes.org

Comment: tried it. all its themes keep all the keywords the same color. i don't think keywords can be differentiated except for between 'return' and other keywords.

Comment: same with creating a theme actually

Comment: humm.. so what's the result we have come up to ?

Comment: it doesn't work with eclipsecolorthemes either. eclipse doesn't allow certain keywords to be distinguished from other keywords in terms of color.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell this is not possible which is bizarre because you can for PHP (the default theme has green for public, mustard yellow for protected and red for private, which I would like for Java).

I've tried themes, too but there just seems to be the one option for Java.

Comment: If they change this, could you comeback and share the news?

Comment: I will if you do

Answer (score 0):

You can only change those which you find under
Windows>Preferences>Java>Editor>Syntax Colouring
 Here modifiers are contained by group "Keywords excluding 'return'". There is no separate group for just modifiers.